# Image size increased more after convert to Base64

Tags: android, base64

I am using **Compressor** third party library for compress the captured images size its working fine and now size is showing KB's but when i convert this images to **BASE64** file size becomes 6MB or more size showing my code is below can some one help me please what should i do for resolve this issue

### code:

```
 File file= new Compressor(this).compressToFile(f);
   String base64File  = getBase64StringFile(file);

     // Converting File to Base64.encode String type using Method
    public static String getBase64StringFile(File f) {

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String encodedFile= "", lastVal;
        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(f.getAbsolutePath());

            byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];//specify the size to allow
            int bytesRead;
            ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Base64OutputStream output64 = new Base64OutputStream(output, Base64.DEFAULT);

            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                output64.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            output64.close();
            encodedFile =  output.toString();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e1 ) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        lastVal = encodedFile;
        return lastVal;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can resolve this issue using some other Compressor tools like FFMPEG.

**Base64 always  increase your file size**

Base64 is often used on binary data that needs to be transmitted across a system that isn't really designed for binary. Depending on what you're doing, you may not even need to encode it. And per the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), on average, a file is expected to **grow about 37% when you base64 encode** it, which is almost exactly what your numbers are.

Comment: FFMPEG Base64 not increased actual file size?

Comment: @AbhiRam use ffmpeg,  not Base64

Comment: @AbhiRam i am editing my answer ffmpge and base64 bothe are diff. tools

Comment: ffmpeg for coverting file to base64 ?,OR for compress to image?

Comment: ffmpeg for file compressing

Comment: I have already used one third party library its working fine ,Problem is not for compressing files i want to convert image into base 64 here increased size i want to find solution in that condition

Comment: @AbhiRam what do you need base64 for? it always increase your data by 33%

Comment: @AbhiRam are using Base64 for image uploading?

Comment: yes i am using Base64 for image uploading that's what the problem

Comment: @AbhiRam then dont use it

Comment: Or ask your backnd team to change it Base64 to multipart

Comment: oh just files have to send instead converting base64?

Comment: @AbhiRam yes it will reduce your code and file size

Comment: @AbhiRam always use multipart for uploading files its better way.